# what happens when u increment array. {a[in.nextInt()]++;}

Tags: java

Please explain what is happening here as i dont understand what is getting incremented...

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[100];
        for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){
            a[in.nextInt()]++; //here 
        }
```

Comment: Well, if you input anything `>= 100` it crashes.

Comment: The integer held at a particular position in the `a` array is being incremented. So if `in.nextInt()` returned 3, then `a[3]` would be incremented. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: what is incremented array index or array values..?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider don't be silly,  assume im giving input<=100. u know im not facing any issue in giving input

Comment: Array values would be incremented. Notice the `++` is outside the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the scanner tied to the system input (keyboard).

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Asking for an integer number `n` from the keyboard:

```
int n = in.nextInt();
```

Declaring an array of 100 int elements (from 0 to 99)

```
int[] a = new int[100];
```

And:

```
        // Running a loop from 0 to the entered n value.
        for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){

            // requesting an int number from keyboard in in.nextInt()
            // and incrementing array element with the index obtained in in.nextInt() 
            a[in.nextInt()]++; 
        }
```

`a[in.nextInt()]++;` can be converted to code:

```
int idx = in.nextInt();
a[idx]++;
```